# How does subtract 9 and -10 in two's complement?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

could somebody please tell me how two's complement done following 9 and -10.

for `9` binary value= `1001`
for `10` binary value =`1010`

take two's complement for -10 = `0110`

9 = `1001`  and -10 = `0110` it comes as finally `1111`. = `15`

but the answer will come `-1`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is -10 cannot be represented by a 4-bit signed integer in two's compliment. You get an overflow - note the sign bit for `0110` is 0! (The same is also true with 9 - note the sign bit is a 1.)

The real answer is, if you're doing this manually, that you need to allocate a buffer big enough to handle your input (and output). If you use 8 bits for example, it should be clear what is happening:

- 9 = `00001001`
- -10 = two's compliment of `00001010` = `11110101` + `00000001` = `11110110`
- `00001001` + `11110110` = `11111111` = -1

---

Now, that being said if you ignore the overflow the logic behind the math still works:

`1111` is not 15 for a 4-bit signed integer. *The sign bit (most significant bit) is 1* indicating it is negative, so you need to interpret it as a two's compliment negative number, in this case -1.

Note that `1111` is 15 for a 4-bit *unsigned* integer, as well as larger size signed integers (which would in actuality be `00...01111` and the sign bit is 0).

It is interesting to note that if you interpret the same numbers as unsigned throughout, the math still works. And thus is the beauty of two's compliment:

- Binary: `1001` + `0110` = `1111`
- Signed (overflow): `9`(!) + `-10`(!) = `-1`
- Unsigned: `9` + `6` = `15`
- Signed (correct): `-7` + `6` = `-1`

Therefore it is imperative you are consistent in signed-ness throughout an entire operation / program. *In your statement "9 = 1001 and -10 = 0110 it comes as finally 1111. = 15" you are mixing a signed interpretation (-10 = `0110`) - ignoring the overflow of course - with an unsigned one (`1111` = 15), which leads to the error.*

Comment: Thank you give a nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that result is incorrect is because with 4-bit numbers, you can only represent the numbers -8 to 7. If you want to write 9 and -10 in two's complement, you need 5 bits (that would be `01001` and `10110`).

Then, `01001` + `10110` = `11111` = -1.

Comment: how `10110` comes can you give me as briefly

Comment: The same way you got to `0110` for -10:
10 = `01010` => -10 = `10101` + `1` = `10110`
Just inverting and adding 1, as usual for two's complement.